# How is the communication between two instances Aplication and BD

Tags: networking, mysql, jboss

I have an instance of applications(jboss) and another instance of BD(mysql) my doubt is that I notice that the communication between these two instances is for a public ip. My Quiestion is.
Is  possible get  better some like private ip between instance of applications(jboss) and another instance of BD(mysql) ?

My both instance are in the same zone.